android studio iguana evaluate is now examine. How do I evaluate code
I noticed the evaluate window in the debugger has changed.  I used to be able to put kotlin code into the window: eg "val x = list.sum(); x + accumulator" and I would get the sum of the values in the list + the value in the accumulator variable.  Now I can step through history but "val =" is no longer valid.
How can I now "evaluate" the results rather than just examine them at a breakpoint?
